# Linear operators that doesn't take their maximal over the "boundary"

Tags: functional-analysis

So recently I have encountered the following lemma:

Given $x \in X$ and $x' \in B(x,r)$, and a linear operator from $X$ to $Y$, one has $sup\{ \Vert Tx'\Vert \} \ge \lVert T \rVert r$ which is slightly surprising to me. (the proof is here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1005.1585.pdf ). I wonder (i) Will there be a strict inequality? (ii) can $x'$ be elements inside the disk such that the inequality still holds?

(The whole statement strangely reminds me of maximum principle of holomorphic functions)

For simplicity, one can set $x=0$ and $r=1$. The first example that comes to mind is integral operators on $L^{2}[0,1]$ spaces, but it seems to not work as given

$\int_{0}^{1} k(t)x(t)dt \le \lVert k \rVert \lVert x \rVert$ and essentially $x$ is a multiple of $k$.

** Thanks for the answer below the situation cleared up a bit. It turns out that our choice of $x$ affects the above inequality. A trivial example is to let $x \equiv 1$ and consider the ball $B(1, 1)$. Now $x' = 1.5\in B(1, 1)$, and let $k(t) = e^{t-1}$ one has $Tx' \gt \Vert T \Vert r$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equality holds for $x=0$ but not for general $x$. Supppose $||Tx'\|\le r \|T||$ for all $x' \in B(x,r)$. Taking $x'=x$ we get $\|Tx\|\le r \|T\|$. Of course, this cannot hold for all $x$ unless $T$ is the zero operator.