# A gap in the "sliding hump" technique

Tags: functional-analysis

I have been stuck in a seemingly trivial proof for a long time. In general, given a family of linear bounded operators $(T_i)_{i\in I}$ from Banach space $X$ to normed $Y$, if $\Vert T_n \Vert $ not uniformly bounded, I wish to find a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $T_n$ is not pointwise bounded for $x$.

Applying the lemma in this question, [Linear operators that doesn't take their maximal over the "boundary"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4884181/829651), to the current problem, one can firstly naively pick a Cauchy sequence $x_n$ such that $\Vert x_n - x_{n-1} \Vert \le \frac{1}{3^n}$ and $\Vert T_n x_n \Vert \ge \Vert T_n \Vert \frac{1}{3^n}$. By completeness, this sequence converges to $x$, and the only problem is that I can't find a proper nice bound for $\Vert x-x_n \Vert $.

$\Vert T_n x \Vert = \Vert T_n(x-x_n) + T_n x_n \Vert \ge \Vert T_n x_n \Vert - \Vert T_n \Vert \Vert x-x_n \Vert (*) $.

To amend such a situation I have to pick $y_n$, so that $y_n:= x_N \text{ such that $N$ is the smallest integer satisfies } \Vert x-x_m \Vert \le \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{3^n} \text{ for } m \ge N$. Then $\Vert y_{n} - y_{n-1} \Vert \le \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{3^{n-1}}$ (the bound is no longer as sharp) and explicitly $(*) \ge \Vert T_n \Vert (\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{3^{n-1}}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{3^n}) = \frac{1}{3^n} \Vert T_n \Vert$

Now, may I ask

(i) Is this proof valid?

(ii) Why am I getting different coefficients from the paper? (Although coefficients don't matter as long as this idea works) https://arxiv.org/pdf/1005.1585.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the bound $\|x - x_{n} \| \leq \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{3^{n}}$ given $n\in\mathbb{N}$ can be obtained from the following argument. Fix $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $m\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n<m$. Then

$$\|x_{m} - x_{n}\| = \left\| \sum_{k=n}^{m-1} (x_{k+1} - x_{k}) \right\| \leq \sum_{k=n}^{m-1}\|x_{k+1} - x_{k}\| \leq \sum_{k=n}^{m-1}\frac{1}{3^{k}} \leq \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{3^{n}}.$$

It follows that

$$\|x - x_{n}\| = \lim_{m\to\infty} \|x_{m} - x_{n}\| \leq \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{3^{n}}.$$

For your estimate, you appear to have used that given $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\|T_{n}(x_{n})\| \geq \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{3^{n-1}} \|T_{n}\|$. But I cannot tell where you obtained that estimate from.

Comment: According to the lemma, $\Vert Tx′ \Vert \ge \Vert Tn \Vert  r$, and r for $y_n$ and $y_{n−1}$ changed from $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$....

Comment: From the lemma, you have $\sup_{x'\in B(x_{n}, r)} \|T_{n}(x') \| \geq \|T_{n}\|r$. But I am still not sure about how you are estimating $\|T_{n}(x_{n})\|$. You can't replace $x_{n}$ with $y_{n}$ in that expression to provide the estimate if that is what you are talking about.

Comment: I don't see the problem in doing so as for any sequence $(y_n)$, the bound only depend on the difference between successive terms...

Comment: Are you replacing the use of the sequence $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ with the use of the sequence $(y_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$? In either case, you have to estimate $\|T_{n}(x_{n})\|$ or $\|T_{n}(y_{n})\|$ below by some useful quantity. I still can't see how you are estimating this below by $\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{3^{n-1}}\|T_{n}\|$. You will need to explain this part in more detail for me to understand it.